# Custom Post Field -> Returning only the word "array"

Tags: custom-field

So I've tried this:

```
$output .= '<span class="team-member-venue">'.get_post_meta( get_the_ID(), 'venueofcoach', true ).'</span>';
```

Where `venueofcoach` is the metaname of the custom post field I created (with the WCK plugin). On the front end between the `<span>` all I get is the word "array".

Any clues as to how to fix this?

Comment: Seems like anywhere I put that I get a blank page I'm afraid...

Comment: Missed a `)` at the end, sorry. Try again `var_dump(get_post_meta( get_the_ID(), 'venueofcoach', true ) );`

Comment: OK, I got this: string(0) ""

Comment: Is `get_the_ID()` returning the correct value or the value that you expect. Where exactly are you using this and how.

Comment: No, but this is how the other lines are working to retrieve other fields like employee name  and position. It is in a template for "employees"... (Jupiter theme: mk_employees.php (shortcodes/mk_employees.php)
)

Comment: You are definitely missing something. The problem for me is, your problem is very localised. Your code is correct, making it very difficult for me to pinpoint what you are doing wrong